# How to send group email from Azure Log Analytics Query result?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

**My Requirement:** I need to send log analytics query result to Group Email basically we are using Azure Data Factories to log all "**Pipeline Metrics**" and "**Activity Metrics**".
To send Email I setup one rule and one "Action Group" and for this "Action Group" initially i setup my Emailid then i Received Email Successfully.However when i give 
Group Email Id(basically i created one group in outloook) it is not sending. Otherway i tried the below solution to send group Email

1.If i select "**Contributor**" Role for  "**Action Group**" then it is sending email to all contributor roles .
2. But i want to send email to these roles "**Monitoring Contributor**" or "**Monitoring Reader**" or "**Reader**" . I tried, but didn't Received mails.

we tried Logic Apps to send Group Email. It worked basically But we don't want use Logic Apps(cost issue).

So, I want solution to send Group Email.

Query :

```
ADFPipelineRun
|join
(
    ADFActivityRun
    |where Status == "Succeeded"  or Status == "Failed"
    |project ActivityStatus = Status,PipelineRunId,ActivityRunId ,ActivityName,ActivityStartTime=Start ,ActivityEndTime=End,FailureReason=ErrorMessage 
)
on $left.CorrelationId == $right.PipelineRunId
|project PipelineName,ActivityName,ActivityStatus,ActivityStartTime,ActivityEndTime,FailureReason
```

Here is image for action group role selection:
[image]

Please help me out from this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure if adding an (O365) Group email to an Action group would land the alert notification email correctly.

But I've tested the same with an [Outlook Distribution Group](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/distribution-groups-e8ba58a8-fab2-4aaf-8aa1-2a304052d2de#bkmk_create) and verified that the alert notification email was successfully sent when the alert was fired.

Unless you have a specific reason to do so, I'd suggest to use an appropriate DG for alert configuration.